# Characteristics of an Operator (T) on a Complex Inner-Product Space with $T^* = -T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthonormal, adjoint-operators, isometry

I am working on the following question, and would very much appreciate a proof-check/some final guidance on the questionable part below!

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex inner-product space and let $T \in $ End$(V)$. Suppose that $T$ satisfies $T^* = -T$.
>
> **(a)** Prove that all eigenvalues of $T$ are purely imaginary.
>
> **(b)** Explain why $V$ has an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors for $T$.
>
> **(c)** The operator $I - T$ is invertible. Show that the operator $S = (I + T)(I - T)^{-1}$ is an isometry.

**Part (A)** 
**My Proof:** Take $v \neq 0$ such that $Tv = \lambda v$. Then we have $\langle Tv, v \rangle = \langle \lambda v, v \rangle = \lambda\langle v, v\rangle$. Further, we can say that  $\langle Tv, v \rangle = \langle v, T^*v\rangle = \langle v, -Tv\rangle = \langle v, -\lambda v\rangle = \overline{-\lambda}\langle v, v\rangle$.

Thus, we must have that $\lambda = \overline{-\lambda}$. If we write $\lambda = a + bi$ then $a + bi = -(a - bi) = -a + bi \implies a = -a \implies a = 0$.

And so with $a = 0$ we have that every eigenvalue must be purely imaginary.

**Part (B)** By the 'Complex Spectral Theorem' we know that an operator $T$ has an orthonormal eigenbasis if it is a normal operator (namely that $TT^* = T^*T$). Now we have that $TT^* = T(-T) = -T^2$ and we have that $T^*T = (-T)T = -T^2$ and so $T$ is normal and the Spectral Theorem can be invoked.

**Part (C)** My thought for part C was to show that $S^*S = I$ which would demonstrate that $S$ is an isometry. However, my attempt at that does not quite work out as I was hoping.

$$
S = (I + T)(I - T)^{-1} \\
\implies S^* = ((I - T)^{-1})^*(I + T)^* \\
= (I - T^*)^{-1}(I + T^*)\\
= (I + T)^{-1}(I - T)
$$

Then $S^*S = (I + T)^{-1}(I - T)(I + T)(I - T)^{-1}$.

Would it be valid to do something like:
$(I - T)(I + T) = (I - T^2) = (I + T)(I - T)$ which would then give $S^*S = I$ as needed?

Comment: That looks fine.

Comment: Everything looks fine and your last idea is sound as well.

Comment: Although if you've got the "basis of eigenvectors" result for Hermitian operators, $iT$ is Hermitian, which might make lighter work.